# Debug XStream with no default constructor

Tags: java, constructor, xstream

I am trying to deserialize a XML using XStream. In there I have object `A` which does not have a default constructor. Then there is object `B` that references object `A`. At that point `A` is instantiated, but all fields are null, even though the values are defined in the XML.

My question is: How can I debug the instantiation of object `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any easy way to hook into the unserializing is to put a break point in the `TreeUnmarshaller`'s convert method where `convertAnother` is called. There you can make the breakpoint on the condition the right type is hit, in my case `A`.
Going down I endend up in `SunLimitedUnsafeReflectionProvider.newInstance` where a new instance is allocated using `sun.misc.Unsafe`.